# Why is the attribute seemingly being reverted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to follow a React tutorial and have not used much Javascript before. As far as I can tell, my code is exactly the same as in the tutorial but it isn't working.

The goal is to change the state of a checkbox by updating the `completed` attribute of the `todo` object

My code for updating the state is below:

```
    handleChange(id) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
                if (todo.id === id) {
                    todo.completed = !todo.completed
                }
                console.log(todo)
                return todo
            })
            console.log(updatedTodos)
            return {
                todos: updatedTodos
            }
        })
    }
```

the part that I don't understand is the console output:

[image]

The 'Wash the dishes' checkbox starts unchecked. I click on it, and it seems to correctly show that `todo.completed` switches to true. But when I log `updatedTodos`, it is false again.

What am I missing? Why does todos.completed get logged as true but show as false when in updatedTodos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Looks like state mutation.

```
handleChange(id) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed // <-- mutates todo object!!
      }
      console.log(todo)
      return todo
    })
    console.log(updatedTodos)
    return {
      todos: updatedTodos
    }
  })
}
```

## Solution

Shallow copy the `todo` object that is being updated as well.

React rerendering works by using a process called [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) that uses shallow reference equality to determine if a certain element needs to be rerendered or not. When you mutate an object but the reference is the same then React bails on rerendering that element (i.e. updating the DOM), so you get stuck with the stale UI.

```
handleChange(id) {
  this.setState(prevState =>
    prevState.todos.map(todo =>
      todo.id === id
        ? {
            ...todo, // <-- spread into new object reference
            completed: !todo.completed, // <-- update property
          }
        : todo,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I still can't figure out what was different between what I wrote vs what the tutorial wrote... but this worked perfectly and is much more elegant

TY!